# Thinking Sphinx with has_many through indexes just fine but saving item crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

Thinking sphinx indexes just fine and lookup works well on my attributes. However, my attempt to save a model instance crashes.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :operation_intervals_locations
  has_many :operation_intervals, :through => :operation_intervals_locations

  define_index "location" do
    # indexes here...

    # tried this syntax
    has operation_intervals(:start_int), :type => :integer 
    has operation_intervals(:end_int), :type => :integer
    has operation_intervals(:days_int), :type => :integer

    # and this one
    has operation_intervals.start_int, :type => :integer 
    has operation_intervals.end_int, :type => :integer
    has operation_intervals.days_int, :type => :integer
  end
end


class OperationInterval < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :start_int, :end_int, :days_int  
end
```

Whenever I do the following:

```
Location.search("foo") # get the search initialized
l = Location.first
l.name = "bar"
l.save(:validate => false)
```

I get the following:

```
# joining is working just fine
OperationInterval Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `operation_intervals`.* FROM `operation_intervals` INNER JOIN `operation_intervals_locations` ON `operation_intervals`.`id` = `operation_intervals_locations`.`operation_interval_id` WHERE `operation_intervals_locations`.`location_id` = 1

# here's where I'm getting my crash
NoMethodError: undefined method `end_int' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xe048450>
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
```

Edit:
I am using delayed delta -- delayed job. I think the issue is happening as thinking_sphinx is trying to push the job to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. Thinking sphinx works well with many to many relationships

The line

```
has operation_intervals.days_int, :type => :integer
```

should **NOT** have `:type => :integer` because a location can have multiple operation_intervals and the real type is array!

using this code instead will solve the issue:

```
has operation_intervals.days_int
```